# bash массив разделения данных

Tags: массивы, bash

Есть файл comp1.txt содержащий ip и принадлежащие ему адреса MAC адреса (кол-во МАС разные):

```
$ cat comp1.txt
192.168.0.1 ff:ff:ff:01:01\nff:ff:ff:01:02
192.168.0.2 ff:ff:ff:02:01\nff:ff:ff:02:02
192.168.0.3 ff:ff:ff:03:01
192.168.0.4 ff:ff:ff:04:01\nff:ff:ff:04:02\nff:ff:ff:04:03
```

и т.д.

Как сделать bash скрипт, которые на основе файла comp1.txt сделает файл comp2.txt:

```
192.168.0.1
MAC1
ff:ff:ff:01:01
MAC2
ff:ff:ff:01:02
192.168.0.2
MAC1
ff:ff:ff:22:01
MAC2
ff:ff:ff:22:02
192.168.0.3
MAC1
ff:ff:ff:03:00
192.168.0.4
MAC1
ff:ff:ff:04:01
MAC2
ff:ff:ff:04:02
MAC3
ff:ff:ff:04:03
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например, так:

```
$ cat comp1.txt | while read ip a; do echo $ip; i=0; for m in ${a//\n/ }; do echo "MAC$((i++))"; echo $m; done; done
```

«хитрость» тут кроется в конструкции `${переменная//строка/замена}`. это [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), реализованный во всех posix-совместимых оболочках (т.е., не только в программе *bash*), возвращает она строку из `переменная`, в которой все встретившиеся `строка` заменены на `замена`.

---

а с помощью программы *awk* будет немного лаконичней:

```
$ cat comp1.txt | awk '{print $1;n=split($2,a,"\\\\n");for(i=1;i<=n;i++){print "MAC"i;print a[i]}}'
```

здесь вообще никаких хитростей, окромя четырёх обратных слэшей, чтобы они прошли через все преобразования и стали в результате одним.

Answer (score 0):

На вскидку так (mac.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    echo $line | awk '{print$1}'
    mac_line=$(echo $line | awk {'print $2'})
    macs=(${mac_line//\\n/ })
    n=1
    for i in "${macs[@]}"
    do
        echo "MAC$n"
        n=$((n+1))
        echo $i
    done
done < "$1"
```

Запуск скрипта:

```
$ ./mac.sh comp1.txt > comp2.txt
```